Playwright tests run slower and ignores global timeout in Azure DevOps
I use Playwright (with NodeJS) to run some tests. It normally takes about 90 minutes to run them all on my local machine or on Azure DevOps. There is a global timeout set to end all the tests after 120 minutes. However, recently the tests have started running for 6 hours (until they hit the Azure timeout).
The tests still work as expected on my local. The slowdown and global timeout failure only occurs in DevOps.
Since the tasks timed out, I don't have the full logs. Everything seems to start normally, but it eventually gives these error messages
Azure DevOps Error Message:
##[Error 1] We stopped hearing from agent Azure Pipelines 2. Verify the agent machine is running and has a healthy network connection. Anything that terminates an agent process, starves it for CPU, or blocks its network access can cause this error. For more information, see: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=846610  
Playwright Task Error Message:
##[section]This job was abandoned. We have detected that logs from the agent may have not finished uploading. We have included our in-memory record of all log lines uploaded before we lost contact with the agent: 
Question:
Does anyone know what could cause Playwright tests run Azure/DevOps to suddenly take so much longer and/or to ignore the Playwright setting's global timeout?
I've tried a few different settings. Everything works as expected when I only run a few tests in Azure. The error only occurs when I run them all.  I'm still trying to narrow down if there's a specific test that causes the error in Azure.

Based on your description, the same test project can work fine on local machine and it can work when running few tests in Azure DevOps. The issue exists when running all tests.
The cause of the issue could be that the Microsoft-Hosted Agent has resource limitation.
Refer to this doc: Capabilities and limitations
When the Agent resource upper limit is reached(e.g. Space 10G), it will affect the running of the test and can cause the test to get stuck until it times out.
To check if the Agent resources has reached to the upper limit, you can enable the option: Enable system diagnostics when running pipeline.

Then you can check the Pipeline log of test task. Then you will find the Memory usage during the pipeline task execution.
For example:
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: D:\ Available 12480.00 MB out of 14333.00 MB, Memory: Used 1862.00 MB out of 7167.00 MB, CPU: Usage 34.28%


If the Agent resources has reached to the upper limit, this means that the Microsoft-Hosted Agent can not meet the requirement of running Playwright tests.
In this case, you can create a Self-hosted Agent on your local machine to run all Playwright tests.

Wow! There are still things that cannot be found on ChatGPT. Your answer helps; thank you.
